# Error while exporting as product, "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found."

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I am getting this error while converting my plugin project to product.

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: org.example.com 1.0.0 (Example 1.0.0)
Missing requirement: Rss and atOM utilitiEs (ROME) 0.9.0.v200803061811 (com.sun.syndication 0.9.0.v200803061811) requires 'package org.jdom 1.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:`

However, in the target platform I already have two versions of org.jdom plugin including the 1.0.0 version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you included them in your .product file? **Everything** needed must be listed in the Dependencies list.

Comment: Yes, the org.jdom plugin is listed in the dependencies of the product file as well!

Comment: We need to see more of the error log, the problem can often be well in to the log